# Handling of 'or' conditions in Ruby vs PHP

Tags: php, ruby

I'm not sure what to call this, so I'll give an example.

In PHP

`1==2 || 2` returns `1` or `true`

In Ruby

`1==2 || 2` returns `2` (The second statement if the first evaluates to false).

Is there any short way to implement similar thing in PHP?

Comment: If the statement were `1==1 || 2`, would you want the integer `1` returned, or `true`?

Comment: In this case I'd want true to be returned. I want the first non false statement to be returned, in this case first is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
1==2 ? 1==2 : 2
```

or in PHP 5.3

```
1==2 ?: 2
```

Comment: I think 2nd one would be the shortest piece of code. Too bad its PHP 5.3+ only.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the result of boolean expressions is always a boolean. So `1==2 || 2` gives `true`.

The best thing I can think of is

```
($var = 1 == 2) || ($var = 2)
```

Then `$var` will be `2`.

Depending on the answer to Matchu's question, you may want:

```
(($var = 1) == 1) || ($var = 2)
```

or

```
($var = 1 == 1) || ($var = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `1 == 2 or 2`?

However, the result might not be the same if you print directly, so you need to put the result inside a variable. Take this example:

```
$result = "a" or 2;
var_dump($result); // prints string(1) "a"

var_dump("a" or 2); // prints bool(true)
```

Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: `$result = "a" or 2;` evaluates to "a" because `=` has higher precedence than `or`.


`$result = false or true` sets $result to false.

Comment: I see. So the you can't use the `or` operator for this scenario?